# variable exists but giving an undefined variable error

Tags: php, mysqli

This is really getting to me.....I keep getting an undefined variable even if it's there!
How do I get rid of this error? Not to mention I'm not even sure the form works because of using xampp and not on a live server

Form on contact.php

```
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 emailForm">
                    <?php if (isset($result)) { echo "$result";} ?>
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Your Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : ''; ?>" />

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['subject'] : ''; ?>" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Your Email Address:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['email'] : ''; ?>" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="message">Your Message:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="message"><?php echo isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['message'] : ''; ?></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value="Submit"/>
                </div>
            </form>
    <!-- Contact Form Ends -->
        </div>
```

sendemail.php code

```
<?php

     if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {              
         if (!$_POST['name']) { 
             $error="<br />Please enter your name"; 
         }       
         if (!$_POST['subject']) { 
             $error.="<br />Please enter a subject"; 
         }          
         if (!$_POST['email']) { 
             $error.="<br />Please enter your email address"; 
         }          
         if (!$_POST['message']) { 
             $error.="<br />Please enter a message"; 
         }                   
         if ($_POST['email']!="" AND !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {          
            $error.="<br />Please enter a valid email address"; 
         }          
         if ($error) { 
             $result='<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>There were error(s) in your form:</strong>'.$error.'</div>';           
         } else { 
            if (mail("support@kf.com", "New Online Message!", "Name: ". $_POST['name']." 
                Name: ".$_POST['name']."             
                Subject: ".$_POST['subject'])) { 
         $result='<div class="alert alert-success text-center"><strong>Thank you!</strong> Please allow 24 to 48 hours for our support team to get back to you. Thank you. </div>';      
         } else {        
            $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry, there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';         
        }    
    }    
}

?>
```

Comment: `$error` is only set if `!$_POST['name']` (using `=`). Otherwise you append to `$error` by using `.=`. You have to initially set `$error = '';`. The reason this works on some servers is because you've disabled PHP notices. Please also note that you're injecting headers into your email allowing anyone to spam any other email (or even a thousand of them) using your contact form.

Comment: so $error before the if statement?? I don't get it

Comment: Headers are yeah. Not even sure how to secure this type of email without the headers and I'm sure it'll be too much to ask anyone here to type up. Thanks for the heads up anyway.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123, I got it now, just curious on the header portion regarding possible spam mail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code :

```html
<?php

     $error = "";
       if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {              
         if ($_POST['name'] == "") { 
             $error .="<br />Please enter your name"; 
         }       
         if ($_POST['subject'] == "") { 
             $error.="<br />Please enter a subject"; 
         }          
         if ($_POST['email'] == "") { 
             $error.="<br />Please enter your email address"; 
         }          
         if ($_POST['message'] == "") { 
             $error.="<br />Please enter a message"; 
         }                   
         if ($_POST['email']!="" AND !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {          
            $error.="<br />Please enter a valid email address"; 
         }          
         if ($error) { 
             $result='<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>There were error(s) in your form:</strong>'.$error.'</div>';           
         } else { 
            if (mail("support@kanifinancial.com", "New Online Message!", "Name: ".  $_POST['name']." 
                Name: ".$_POST['name']."             
                Subject: ".$_POST['subject'])) { 
         $result='<div class="alert alert-success text-center"><strong>Thank you!</strong> Please allow 24 to 48 hours for our support team to get back to you. Thank you. </div>';      
         } else {        
            $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry, there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';         
        }    
    }    
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined $error variable in if block it's scope is in only in if block.Define it outside the if block  at the beginning.